# openapi showing wrong status codes for different methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

I have a simple controller like this

```
  @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
  Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return employeeService.getEmployee(id);
  }

  @GetMapping("/employees")
  List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return employeeService.getEmployees();
  }

...

  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Employee not found")
  @ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorData> employeeNotFoundHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorData, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }

  // For post requests 
  @ResponseBody
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, reason = "Some message")
  @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
  ResponseEntity<ErrorData> someExceptionHandler(SomeException ex) {
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorData, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
  }
```

**The problem** 
when I check OpenAPI's output, it shows that 
`GET /employees` could return (`200`, `404`  or `422`), 
and `GET /employees/{id}` could return (`200`, `404`  or `422`)

Shouldn't it be only `200` for `GET /employees`? 
and (`200` or `404`) for `GET /employees/{id}`?